# imagesLoaded jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, json

I can't seem to wrap my head around the deferred method of the imagesLoaded plugin. I don't know how to use it in my specific case. I'm getting photos from an external source using JSON. Everything is loaded into #photographs. I want to achieve that everything is hidden while loading all the photos (showing a big loader animation); when 15 photos have been loaded, remove the big loading animation and show a small one and keep loading the rest of the photos. When i all photos have been loaded, hide the small loading animation.

I have the following code but it's wrong of course, since the callback is only called when everything has been loaded. I'm looking towards .progress() method..

```
$('#photographs').imagesLoaded(function($images) {
        var totalAmount = $images.length;
        if(($images.length) > 15) {
            $("#photographs, #loader").fadeIn("fast");
            $("#bigloader").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#photographs").gridalicious({
                gutter: 2,
                animate: true,
                effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
                width: 430,
                complete: onComplete()
            });
        } else if(($images.length) == totalAmount) {
            $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");
        };
    });
```

Something like this?

```
var dfd = $("#photographs").imagesLoaded();

    dfd.progress(function( isBroken, $images, $proper, $broken ) {
        var totalAmount = $images.length;

        if(($proper.length) > 15) {
            $("#photographs, #loader").fadeIn("fast");
            $("#bigloader").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#photographs").gridalicious({
                gutter: 2,
                animate: true,
                effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
                width: 430,
                complete: onComplete()
            });
        }
    });
```

Edit: info about the progress method can be found here https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: First of all you should change "complete: onComplete()" to "complete: onComplete", as you are passing the result of a function instead of a referrence.

Comment: Your usage of .progress looks fine. What is it not doing? At this point you haven't told us whether or not it is working. Are you using jQuery 1.7 or newer?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.3, so yes. It was not working properly: it starts loading everything at random and never passes the point where it should check that 15 images have been loaded.

Comment: How far along does totalAmount get? how many times does the progress callback happen? Where is it failing? how is it failing?

Comment: totalAmount is always 125 (it's the current number of images that gets loaded through JSON). Therefore, the last check (($images.length) == totalAmount)) is 125 = 125. The callback process only happens once, one the images have been loaded. That's why i'm looking into the progress method.. (take a look at the online example: http://www.mathijsdelva.be/2013 (jquery-config.js)

Comment: Also, with the progress method, the images show up in random order and are very heavy to load (meaning the 15 check is not working imo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the handler to the images themselves, so that it is fired every time an image is loaded:

```
var loaded = 0;
var totalAmount = $('#photographs img').length;

$('#photographs img').each(function() {
    loaded;
    $(this).imagesLoaded(function($images) {
        loaded++;
        if (loaded > 15) {
            // stuff to do when more than 15 images
        } else if (loaded == totalAmount) {
            // stuff to do when all images loaded
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems logical, but it's not working. It keeps on loading but nothing gets executed in the if structure..

Comment: @MathijsDelva Could you trace `loaded` and see if its value is increasing?

Comment: console.log only produces 1, then stops

Comment: @MathijsDelva Are you putting `console.log` immediately after `loaded++`? Also, this would be a lot easier if you could put up a jsfiddle that I could examine.

Comment: mathijsdelva.be/2013 (wip) (it's a bit of hassle to set up a jsfiddle for this)

Comment: And yes, immediatly after loaded++

Comment: @MathijsDelva Your page doesn't seem to be using the code I've suggested.

Comment: Yes i know, i'm sorry, i currently have the code ready for Kevin B (see other answer)

Comment: It does seem to be working, but the else if does nothing. Also, it's not the desired outcome. The images are all loading at once; it's very choppy.

Comment: @MathijsDelva The images load all at once anyway, since there is no sequence in which the server is supposed to send responses. Images with a smaller image size will load first

Comment: Okay, thank you. It certainly helped a bit, although i'm still struggling to get this thing right.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).imagesLoaded(function);
```

This method of using ImagesLoaded seems to register your function to the "always" event. Try explicitly handling the always event, but add a handler for the "progress" event first, like this:

```
$(selector).imagesLoaded()
    .progress(function( instance, image ) {
        $(progressBarSelector).val( $(progressBarSelector).val() + 1);    
    })
    .always(function(){
         $(progressBarSelector).hide();
    });
```

My progress code wasn't being executed either until I changed the order by explicitly defining this progress event handler.